# Relation schema: How to solve this?

Tags: database, schema, relation

Relation schema: How to solve this?

```
R(A,B,C,D,E)

F={A→B, B→C, D→E, CE→A}
```

I want to find all candidate key in R.
Is it possible to prove the relationship between A/B/C/E to D?

Comment: *" I know D is one of the candidate key . . . "* D is not a candidate key.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' can you tell me which one is candidate?

Comment: Just by inspection, AD is one candidate key.